# Electron in production mode pointing URL calls to file URL instead of proxy URL

Tags: reactjs, api, build, electron, electron-builder

I have created a simple application using React and Electron that handles few requests, the electron app works fine on dev mode, but during production, there is an issue, all the API calls, written in the code are pointing to file URL: /C:/... instead of proxy mapping to localhost.

[image]

Code Snippet is as:

```
export default class App extends Component {

    state = { username: null };
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/getUsername')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(user => this.setState({ username: user.username }));
   }

   render() {
    const { username } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <img src={ReactImage} alt="react" style={{ height: '250px' }} />
            {username ? <h1>{`Hello there, I'm ${username}`}</h1> : <h1>Loading.. please wait!</h1>}
            <Link to="/users">See More users</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

So I have no idea why this is happening, so it would of great help if anyone knows how to resolve it.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you show the code that is making the call?

Comment: @CUGreen updated the question to add code snippet.

Comment: I see. You will need to add the hostname to the url. eg. `http://localhost/api/getUsername`

Comment: @CUGreen But I have configured proxy in my application, and it is working fine during dev mode but in the prod mode the issue starts to show up.
`devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
        }
    }`

Comment: Production uses the file system not the dev server url, so you will need to host the api and use the full hostname.

Comment: @CUGreen got your point, will try to implement the required changes and if there is any issue will let you know.

Comment: When an electron app consumes an api, it is normally a request to a remote host. If you need to do it locally for some reason, then I have been able to achieve this using express. Otherwise, perhaps it is best to use a local database instead of an api.

Comment: @CUGreen I get, but alternatively, I have used electron-is-dev to check if electron is on prod or dev and changed the api mappings accordingly.